# Multiple generic lists in interface

Tags: c#

I'm curious if is there better approach for creating interface with multiple generics objects. Especially I don't like look of this IScope interface. I'm new in using generics but I find them very nice fitting in my project. Is there a possibility that class that implements this interface is not forced to define object type at declaration like this?

```
public abstract class Scope : IScope<Config.Timebase, Config.Coupling, Config.Slope, Config.VerticalSensitivity, Config.TriggerMode, Config.RecordLength, int, float>

public interface IScope<A, B, C, D, E, F>
{
    List<IParameter<A>> AvailableTimebaseSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<B>> AvailableCoupleSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<C>> AvailableTriggerSlopeSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<D>> AvailableSenitivitySettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<E>> AvailableTriggerModeSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<F>> AvailableRecordLength { get; }

    IParameter<A> TimeBase { get; set; }
    IParameter<B> Couple { get; set; }
    IParameter<C> TriggerSlope { get; set; }
    IParameter<D> Sensitivity { get; set; }
    IParameter<E> TriggerMode { get; set; }
    IParameter<F> RecordLength { get; set; }
}

 public interface IParameter<T>
{
    string ParameterName { get; }
    string ParameterValue { get; }
    string ParameterUnit { get; }
    bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    T GetParameter { get; }
}
```

Comment: Let's do the YAGNI check: Is it *really* a necessary requirement that RecordLength can be something else than `float` or that your TimeBase can be something else than a `Config.TimeBase`? If not, get rid of all the genericity in IScope and just keep `IParameter` generic. Note that IScope does not need to be generic to make use of the generic IParameter class.

Comment: I simply want to be sure that when I get object from the list I can set it to corresponding property. I don't want to strict them to basic type like int because I think that It would be better to put here anything. I thought about using Object type but that approach forced to use boxing/unboxing, and I don't think that is good approach at all.

Comment: This is just plain horrible. Generic means *generic*; `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. should be allowed to be *anything*. Does that hold true in your code? If your valid generic types are a bound (finite) set, then by definition they are not generic, so don't make them generic.

Comment: My scope has several structures of supported parameters and I don't want to restrict interface to works only with this type of data. I thought that from gui point of view this is brilliant: we have supported, described list of objects that I can simply get from list and set to scope object and I don't want to think anything more, what is this, is this that exact type of enum or maybe int or float.

Comment: @JanKowalski: Since your property is called Available*Timebase*Settings, you already (by name) restrict it to values representing a time base. Again: Is it really realistic that someone would use a `Boolean`, a `FormatException` or a `BitArray` to represent a time base? My suggestion would be to keep `IParameter<T>` generic (as it is), but remove genericity from IScope, i.e. replace `List<IParameter<A>> AvailableTimebaseSettings { get; }` with `List<IParameter<Config.Timebase>> AvailableTimebaseSettings { get; }`, etc.

Comment: @JanKowalski: And if you want to be open to future extensions, you could use `List<IParameter<ITimebase>> AvailableTimebaseSettings { get; }` instead.